# Is there a way to fast travel in Skyward Sword?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

Is there a way to fast travel when you are in the sky?  Something along the lines of the whistle in the first game or whatever was in Windwaker?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there isn't a fast travel option, but then the sky isn't *that* large. It doesn't take that long to get where ever you need to go.

However, there are strategically placed boost rocks which you can use to increase your speed.

Comment: Especially if you use the boost rocks.

Comment: Though still annoying to _have_ to fly those distances between missions, especially if you are goddess chest hunting.